# how to convert spark rdd to structured streaming for time window process in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

how can i convert spark rdd to structured streaming for time window process?

for example, i want to query data set from es and process them as structured streaming.

```
conf = {"es.resource" : "index/type"}  # assume Elasticsearch is running on localhost defaults
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
                     "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
                     "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
                     conf=conf)
```

and `streamdf = function(rdd)`

```
streamdf.groupBy(
    window(streamdf.event_time, windowDuration, slideDuration),
    streamdf.mykey
).count().orderBy('window')
```

what is the function?

Comment: You can use window functions on non-streaming rdds/dataframes.

Comment: I think the windowing functions on RDDs/DStreams only operate on rows, not on e.g. event time